# How to make ActiveRelation<< do not implicitly persist added entries in the Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

If I have two classes A and B with the given relation:

```
class A < AR::Base; has_many :bs; end
class B < AR::Base; belongs_to :a; end
```

when executing:

```
a=A.new
a.bs << B.new
```

both a and the elements inserted in the Bs list are not persisted.
Though, if we invoke a.save after invoking new:

```
a=A.new
a.save!
a.bs << B.new
```

the newly created B is imediately persisted.

How can I avoid this implicit saving behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't unfortunately. From the rails docs:

> **collection<<(object, …)**
>
> Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the collection’s primary key. *Note that this operation instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object*.

Italics are my emphasis.